# Opinion on Paul Halmos's introduction in his book Naive Set Theory

Tags: set-theory

I just started reading Paul Halmos's book *Naive Set Theory* - to check if the field would be an interesting area to work on ...

However, in the Introduction of the book, Paul Halmos stated something to the effect that it is a truism in mathematics that the more general a subject area is, then the less deep it is ... and Paul Halmos stated that set theory is one of the math areas that deal with very general topics .... ergo, set theory is not very deep (at least that's the impression I got upon reading Halmos's Introduction)

But I would like to get some opinions on how to understand the nuances / contextualize this comment by Halmos, given that the ideas presented in set theory all seem pretty deep for me ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual quote is "It is a mathematical truism, however, that the more generally a theorem applies, the less deep it is." Halmos writes about the theorems he discusses, not the general field of set theory.

Moreover, the focus of the book is on the set theory that is needed even for areas quite remote from set theory, for the aims "of a prospective mathematician anxious to study groups, or integrals, or manifolds." For the purposes of such fields, the set-theoretic tools needed should mostly become, at some point, fairly trivial. This is similar to understanding basic induction; at some point this should not be where one gets stuck.

That being said, set theory as a research area is a very deep field. As is number theory, even though understanding what natural numbers are is not.